# Kotlin Annotation: Get interface inner annotated properties

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations

#### Overview

I'm trying to build my first annotation processor and it's going pretty well. I am creating a code generating processor that basically generates `SharedPreferences` for a defined interface.  My current annotations are `SharedPrefs` and `Default`.  `@SharedPrefs` informs the processor that the file is an interface and needs a generated prefs file. `@Default` is what I annotated some properties in the interface as in order to let the processor know what to set the default value to. There can be multiple files defined as `@SharedPrefs`.

#### Implementation

I currently use the following code to get a list of files annotated with `@SharedPrefs` and the `@Default`s:

```java
roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(SharedPrefs::class.java)?.forEach { element ->
  ...
  roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Default::class.java)?.forEach {
    ...
  }
}
```

`@SharedPrefs`:

```java
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
annotation class SharedPrefs(val showTraces: Boolean = false)
```

`@Default`:

```java
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
annotation class Default(val defaultValue: String = "[null]")
```

In Use:

```java
@SharedPrefs
interface InstanceSettings {
    var wifiPassword: String
    @Default("20")
    var count: Int
}
```

#### Problem

As is, the inner `forEach` is returning *all* properties from *all* files annotated with `@Default`.  The code generation works fine, but this doesn't seem like the best way forward.  Is there a way to get just the properties w/in the current `@SharedPrefs` class that I'm processing?  For instance, something like:

```java
roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(SharedPrefs::class.java)?.forEach { element ->
  ...
  element.methodToGetAnnotatedProperties(Default::class.java)?.forEach {
    ...
  }
}
```

#### *** EDIT ***

I found that, for methods that I annotate

```java
@SomeAnnotation
fun someMethod()
```

I can loop through the `element.enclosingElements` and find if it has an annotation using `enclosingElement.getAnnotation(<SomeAnnotation::class.java>)`.  Unfortunately, and correct me if I'm wrong here, I can't annotate interface variables with an annotation with `AnnotationTarget.FIELD` since they don't have a backing field since it's an interface and they're not implemented.  Therefore, I'm using `AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY`.  When looping through the enclosing elements, all of the variables show up as getters and setters.  For the example above for `InstanceSettings`, I get `getWifiPassword`, `setWifiPassword`, `getCount` and `setCount`. I *do not* get an element for just `wifiPassword` or `count`.  Calling `getAnnotation(Default::class.java)` will always return null on these since they are generated.

Also, any other resources on annotation processing that anyone knows of would be a great addition in the comments.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I've found the solution:

For the example of `InterfaceSettings`:

```java
@SharedPrefs
interface InstanceSettings {
    var wifiPassword: String
    @Default("20")
    var count: Int
}
```

The simplified generated Java code is :

```
public interface InstanceSettings {
   @NotNull
   String getWifiPassword();

   void setWifiPassword(@NotNull String var1);

   int getCount();

   void setCount(int var1);

   public static final class DefaultImpls {
      public static void count$annotations() {
      }
   }
}
```

The element returned when calling `roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Default::class.java)` is `count$annotations`. So when I call `getEnclosingElement()`, `DefaultImpls` is returned. If I call `getEnclosingElement()` *again*, `InstanceSettings` is returned. I actually call `getSimpleName()` on that result and compare it with the className from the item annotated with `@SharedPrefs` to see if it is a child:

```
roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(SharedPrefs::class.java)?.forEach { element ->
  val className = element.simpleName.toString()
  val defaults = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Default::class.java)?.filter {
    // it.enclosingElement -> DefaultImpls
    // DefaultImpls.enclosingElement -> com.mypackage.InstanceSettings
    it.enclosingElement.enclosingElement.simpleName == className
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar question in java was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27210759/jsr269-annotation-processing-getelementsannotatedwith-return-all-the-annotated)

Here is how you can create an extension function which will do job for you!

```kotlin
roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(SharedPrefs::class.java)?.forEach { element ->
    ...
    roundEnv.findNestedElements(SharedPrefs::class, Default::class)?.forEach {
        ...
    }
}

fun <T> RoundEnvironment.findNestedElements(parent: KClass<*>, child: KClass<T>): List<Element>? {
    val childs = this.getElementsAnnotatedWith(child.java)
    val list = ArrayList<Element>()
    for (element in childs)
    {
        if (element.getEnclosingElement().getAnnotation(parent.java) != null)
        {
            list.add(element)
        }
    }
    return if(list.isEmpty()) null else list
}
```

Comment: the line `element.getEnclosingElement().getAnnotation(parent.java)` returns `DefaultImpls`.  I _believe_ this is because the `getElementsAnnotatedWith(Default::class.java)` is returning the generated getters/setters and not a backing field.  See my edit above

Comment: Sorry, minor correction to the comment above : `element.getEnclosingElement()` returns `DefaultImpls`.  Calling `getAnnotation(parent.java)` returns null (as expected).